# Extending Console in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, console

I would am working on an app that's written in JavaScript. I'd like to extend that `Console` object. Is there a way do that? Currently, I have:

```
Console.prototype.execute = function() {
  console.log('execute this...');
}
```

Then, in my code, I have:

```
console.execute();
```

When I run my page, I see the following in the console window:

`Console is not defined`

This implies I can't extend `Console`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The console API is not standardized. How to do it and if it's possible at all likely depends on the environment the code runs in. If `console` is extensible, you could just do `console.execute = ...;`.

Comment: Just use `console.execute = function(){`…`};`.

Comment: Adding it to the console object itself makes even more sense when you think it's a singleton

Comment: In what environment are you? In node, there's a [`Console` module](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html) which you could (but shouldn't) extend.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a Console function that maps to the console object. You can check it using:

```
console.constructor.
  => function Object() { [native code] }
```

or

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(console) 
  => Object {}
```

It is just an object. 
Just add your functions to the console object:

```
console.execute = function() {
   console.log('execute this...');
}
```

Comment: That depends on the browser, actually.

Comment: @Bergi- this correct, but Chrome and Firefox (both take 85% of the market share) don't implement it using prototype so it is basically irrelevant to implement it like this, anyway you probably won't be able to instantiate a new Console type in the browsers that support the feature.